# jQuery script not working, but can't see the issue

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My script looks perfectly fine to me - I can't see the problem, when I click the link it does nothing.

Within the head tag in my index.php:

```
<!-- scripts -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js"></script>
```

js/script.js :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#changeDP').click(function(){
        $('#profile_picture_change').show();
        $('#outer_container').hide();
    });
});
```

and I have each of the corresponding tags (they are all correctly closed):

`<div class="profile_picture_change" style="display:none;">`

`<div class="outer_container">`

`<a id="changeDP" href="#">`

Thank you your help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 7):

You're referring to the element **classes** as if they were **ids**.

```
    $('.profile_picture_change').show();
    $('.outer_container').hide();
```